# Typo for info on silver/gold badges

Tags: bug, badges, spelling

When you show the info of a badge by hovering the mouse over it, e.g. for the nice/good/great question it shows:

- bronze badge: Question score of 10 or more
- silver badge:: Question score of 25 or more
- gold badge:: Question score of 100 or more

The `::` is a typo for all silver/gold badges.